# ElasticSearch SQL API format dateime

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, date-formatting

I connect to ElasticSearch via (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master//sql-jdbc.html). so that my application server can generate queries similar to SQL syntax. SQL API syntax is understandable, but I can't figure out how to change the format of the returned date. eg: request:

```
select "@timestamp" from a_nlb
limit 10
```

Returns a format

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.s
```

How to bring the output to the format DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss?
trunc and to_date are absent

Answer (score 0):

from the doc

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-functions-datetime.html#sql-functions-datetime-datetimeformat

```
SELECT DATETIME_FORMAT(CAST('2020-04-05' AS DATE), 'dd/MM/YYYY') AS "date";

      date
------------------
05/04/2020
```